# How to generate Conditional distribution from Gaussian Copula in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, conditional-statements, probability

Matlab has a built-in function to simulate from copulas: `copularnd`
I need to have a conditional Gaussian Copula.
I had a suggestion for **Clayton Copula** by another user: 
[Clayton Copula Sampling](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38157/how-to-sample-from-a-copula-in-matlab)
for which the code is :

Can anybody by an example show, how the coding can be done, using ***GAUSSIAN Copula***?

%% Simulations of Clayton copulas using conditional cdf

```
%Example for theta=4
n=3000;
theta=5;
u=rand(1,n);
y=rand(1,n);
v=((y.^(1/(1+theta)).*u).^(-theta)+1-u.^(-theta)).^(-1/theta);

x1=norminv(u);
x2=norminv(v);

plot(x1,x2,'.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this code:](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/46177/simulating-from-a-multivariate-clayton-copula/48678?noredirect=1#comment69354_48678)

```
%%Simulations of bivariate Gaussian copulas 

%Example for rho=0.5
n=30000;
rho=0.5;
x1=norminv(rand(1,n));
x2=norminv(rand(1,n));
X = [x1; x2];

C = [1, rho; rho,1]; %2x2 Correlation matrix

cholesky = chol(C,'lower'); %lower triangular matrix of C using Cholesky decomposition

Copsims = cholesky*X;

c1 = Copsims(1,:);
c2 = Copsims(2,:);

plot(c1,c2,'.')

corrcoef(c1,c2) %check for empirical rho, not on point the initial rho because of sampling error
```